# can not get keras set up using conda

Tags: python, keras, urllib, conda

I have been trying to create a conda environment and install keras all afternoon. I have used pip to remove anything that wasn't part of my conda environment. I have deleted my conda environment and started fresh about a dozen times.

Most of my attempts are something like :

```
conda env create -n keras python=3.5
activate keras
conda install  keras
python
import keras
```

At this point, I get a full page stack trace that ends with

```
    from six.moves.urllib.request import urlopen
ImportError: cannot import name 'urlopen'
```

Comment: which backend are you using?

Comment: Tensorflow, but I did not specify it. I have seen messages saying it is using tf backend. Keep in mind , the initial import of Keras generates the error.

Comment: if `import tensorflow` works, then i suggest using tensorflow's built-in keras, unless you think you might be using a different backend at some later point.

Comment: if I type :    "import tensorflow" I get the same error.  The first part of the stack trace mentions this line:  "...\python\keras\__init__.py, line 24"

Comment: Now I have uninstalled all my versions of python and anaconda and reinstalled the latest anaconda. The import fails with the original error message if I run it from a script file but it works fine if I copy and paste the same command at a prompt.

Comment: Ok, I was able to finally run the import and I got no error. After I reinstalled everything I made a new conda env, used conda to install pip in that env, then activated the env and used pip to install keras and later tensorflow. The issue might have been because I was trying to do a "conda install -n keras keras" and that didn't work for whatever reason.

Comment: One other aspect of this is that my original script still does not run in the original directory. Every time I run it from that dir a folder called __pycache__ gets recreated and there is a *.pyc file in that dir. I delete the dir, try again, it fails w/ original error and the dir is recreated once again. When I made a new work folder and put my script in there the same command runs w/o error and does not create the __pycache__ directory. Does anybody know what this is about?